# Show that the below polynomial has a root in [0,1] without using Rolle's theorem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, polynomials

> Show that the polynomial $p(x)=a_0+a_1 x+a_2x^2+\cdots+ a_nx^n$
> has a zero in $[0,1]$ when it is given that,
> $$\frac{a_1}{2}+\frac{a_2}{6}+\cdots+ \frac{a_n}{(n+1)(n+2)}=0.$$

I know there exists an answer to this using Rolle's theorem, but I wanted to see if we could find $a_0$ in terms of a series of $a_i$ and then argue that $p(0)$ and $p(1)$ are opposite in signs.

Comment: Is it $\frac{a_0}{2}+\frac{a_1}{6}+\cdots+ \frac{a_n}{(n+1)(n+2)}=0$?

Comment: The formula suggests that integrating twice might help.

Comment: I realize integrating twice might help, but I have also attempted the solution by finding a0 as a series of ai and then arguing that p(0) and p(1) are opposite in signs; I just want to know if this is also a correct approach